# Regular expression to restrict Extended ASCII character set

Tags: regex, vb.net, validation

I have multi lingual application which creates xml files but Extended ASCII characters from 168 to 254 (¿⌐¬½¼¡«»░▓│┤╡╢╖╕╣║╗╜╛┐└┴┬├) are not supposed in XML tags so, I would like to restrict user from entering.

I tried restricting everything besides alphanumeric, underscore and dash but it would not allow accented characters ó ç õ which are part of extended ASCII. Here is regx `"^[a-zA-Z0-9\s.\-_]+$"`

Second option was to create a string of all symbols from 168 to 254 and check if string contains any of them but not sure if it is reliable and accurate solution.

What is best way to filter input for Extended ASCII character set ?

[Link](http://www.web-wise-wizard.com/programming/ascii-ibm-extended-character-set.html) to Extended ASCII character set table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although @Oded suggest was applicable but I used following solution:

```
Dim filteredInput as string

Private const XML_RESTRICTED_CHARACTERS as string ="[☺☻♥♦♣♠•◘○◙♂♀♪♫☼►◄↕‼¶§▬↨↑↓→←∟↔▲▼#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`¢£¥₧ƒªº¿⌐¬½¼¡«»░▒▓│┤╡╢╖╕╣║╗╝╜╛┐└┴┬├─┼╞╟╚╔╩╦╠═╬╧╨╤╥╙╘╒╓╫╪┘┌█▄▌▐▀αßΓπΣσµτΦΩδ∞φε∩≡±≥≤⌠⌡÷≈°∙·√ⁿ²■""}{]"

filteredInput =Regex.Replace(strInput.ToLower(), XML_RESTRICTED_CHARACTERS, "")
```

Answer (score 5):

Rather you can make use of `range` in character class, to exclude specific range of characters using their `Hex Codes`: -

```
[^\xA8-\xFE]
```

The above regex will match any character except those in the given range. Those are the hex codes for the range you posted - `[168, 254]`

Comment: yes they are from 128-255. Since 128 to 167 are accented characters (e.g ó ç õ) being used by forign languages so I did not want to restrict them

Comment: after adding above range here it my regx: ^(a-z|A-Z|0-9)*[^\xA8-\xFE/>|'&%$@!~`,./?\\<*:""]*$ but it also restricts below xA8 ?

Answer (score 1):

> Second option was to create a string of all symbols from 168 to 254 and check if string contains any of them but not sure if it is reliable and accurate solution.

Yes, this is a reliable and accurate solution. It is also more lightweight than regular expressions.