# Regex to disallow extended ASCII characters

Tags: asp.net, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that will disallow extended ASCII characters, inorder to apply it on a text box in an ASP.NET application. Please help!

Comment: Should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970327/regular-expression-to-restrict-extended-ascii-character-set

Comment: It might be easier to specify which characters you will allow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will only match a string that contains only ASCII characters

```
^[\x00-\x7F]+$
```

To disallow only the extended ASCII characters you could use

```
^[^\x80-\xFF]+$
```